# Not able to submit refund (eCheck)

Tags: api, transactions, authorize.net

I send such request to refund payment to Authorize:

```
<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>***</name>
    <transactionKey>**********</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>refundTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>***</amount>
    <profile>
      <customerProfileId>***</customerProfileId>
      <paymentProfile>
        <paymentProfileId>***</paymentProfileId>
      </paymentProfile>
    </profile>
    <refTransId>***</refTransId>
  </transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>
```

but I got such error

```
<error> 
    <errorCode>101</errorCode> 
    <errorText>The given name on the account and/or the account type does not match the actual account.</errorText> 
</error>
```

I get this error only for some transactions.
I send only customerProfileId, paymentProfileId. Please let me know why this error is returned and how the name or type could be different?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [routing number for that account may not match the bank](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/eCheck-test-txns-on-sandbox-today-can-t-get-an-approval/td-p/59415). This looks like an issue on Authorize.Net's side.

Comment: I have same thinking, I submitted form to Authorize week ago but didn't get answer...

Comment: Who is providing the routing number for you? I wonder if there is a way to find an alternate routing number that wouldn't cause this issue.

Comment: I liked [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030877/how-to-convert-php-website-to-mobile-application#comment91012275_52030877) so much I felt compelled to upvote you somewhere. I wonder the same thing every day, multiple times a day...

Comment: User provide the routing number when do payment, then i get from Authorize customerProfileId and paymentProfileId and save it. I try to use it for refund. 
I have gotten information about PP and about transaction (Get Customer Profile and Get Transaction Details). I got same error when use it for refund. (used bankRoutingNumberMasked and bankAccountNumberMasked )